# Incompatible bounds error: Java Predicate generics

Tags: java, generics, java-8, guava, predicate

I have an incompatible bounds error in the following code:

```
    Predicate<Integer> pred;
    Iterator<Integer> daysToRunIter = Iterators.cycle(daysToRunInt);

    if(nowHourOfDay >= schedule.getHourOfDay()){
        pred = val -> val > currDayOfWeek;
    } else {
        pred = val -> val == currDayOfWeek;
    }
    Iterator<Integer> subset = Iterators.find(daysToRunIter,pred); //ERROR
```

The error that I get: 
[image]

It looks like I'm providing compatible type `Integer`, why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: As the doc states, `find` returns an element of type `T` from an `Iterator<T>` (_"Returns the first element in iterator that satisfies the given predicate"_). So `subset` should be an `Integer` I guess...

Comment: are you sure the element exists? Try adding a default value as a third parameter in your find method call. Something like
`Iterators.find(daysToRunIter,pred, 1);`

Comment: @AlexisC. Thanks, this did resolve it! I'll put this as answer and give credit to you.

Comment: @OlivierPoulin thanks, I'm actually going to try tryFind() from guava instead of just find()

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of error messages; they're hard to read and search engines can't see them, meaning other people with the same error can't find this question by searching for the error text.

Comment: @dimo414 sorry about that, intelliJ wasn't showing it well either, so I couldn't copy and paste. Do you want me to rewrite the error message in text?

Answer (score 2):

```
Integer subset = Iterators.find(daysToRunIter,pred);
```

resolved the error.

Credit goes to @AlexisC.